# How to record sound from inside speaker using matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, record, audio-recording

I want to record sound from built-in speaker using matlab in the PC. ( I use Tablet PC : dell venue pro 8, I want to record sound from sound card in the PC)

it works very well if I plug in earphone to my tablet PC. But it doesn't work when I didn't plug in earphone and just play audio file.( Of course, My Tablet PC has built-in speaker, So I can listen audio file)

I think these two case use same sound card ( 1 : sound from earphone, 2: sound from built-in spearker). But first case can record sound using below code, second I couldn't.
I can not understand..

```
recObj = audiorecorder(44100,16,1);
disp('Start speaking.')
recordblocking(recObj, 3);
disp('End of Recording.');
```

Actually, I tried to these four case

```
recObj = audiorecorder(44100,16,1,0);
recObj = audiorecorder(44100,16,1,1);
recObj = audiorecorder(44100,16,1,2);
recObj = audiorecorder(44100,16,1,3);
```

because I have 2 input/output audio device and they have IDs which are 0~3 in my tablet PC.

Please help, I spent really a lot of time to solve it.TT

Comment: What is the return from `devinfo = audiodevinfo` - in particular, what does `devinfo.input` show?  Obviously you can't record from an output device (speaker).

Comment: The return value is

devinfo = 

     input: [1x2 struct]
    output: [1x2 struct]

and 

devinof.input(1,1) = Name : '~~~' DriverVersion : 'Windows DirectSound' ID : 0 

devinof.input(1,2) = Name : '~~~' DriverVersion : 'Windows Directsound' ID : 1